# Pound sign in html email messes up charset?

Tags: character-encoding

I have an HTML email that pulls non-english characters from the database. By setting the charset as UTF-8 the characters are properly displayed in the email.

However, as part of my email body there's an anchor link (`<a href='#here'>here</a>`) which uses a pound sign. When I include this line of code, then the non-english characters later in the email are garbled. When I exclude that line - the characters are fine.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: note the 'pound sign' could also be called a hash, otherwise it could be confused with the currency symbol - or is it the currency symbol to which you refer?

Comment: @akf: I've edited it to make the link obvious :)

Comment: @Susan: you might be seeing a bug specific to the mail client you're testing with. Can you reduce the problem to a small testcase and state how it fails and with which software and version?

Comment: By "how it fails", I mean listing what you expect to see and what you actually see.

Comment: This is a pound sign: `£`. The symbol you're talking about is a hash symbol (a.k.a., the octothorpe).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the HTML # number?

```
&#35;
```

Does that work?